# Passing data to the application using Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, flags, android-pendingintent

I have created two applications.

One application is message receiver (**app1**) and another application (**app2**) is for doing other tasks based on the message.

First application (app1) receives a message, creates the notification and shows up in the top.
When user clicks the notification, it invokes the another application (app2) to do the other tasks based on the message.

If the application (app2) is not running, it should be started. If it is already running, the instance should be displayed and tasks to be done.

I am using following code:

```
protected void displayNotification() {

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Bundle xtra = new Bundle();

        Intent ntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        ntent.setClassName("com.example.mytestapp",
                "com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity");

        xtra.putString("id", "8610B0DD");
        xtra.putParcelable("message", msg);

        ntent.putExtras(xtra);
        ntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                ntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                pendingIntent);
        final int button_Click = 1;
        nm.notify(button_Click, notification);
}
```

This works fine but it **creates multiple instances** of another application (app2).

Is there any way to prevent creating this multiple copies?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting "singleTask" or "singleInstance" for the launchMode of the activity?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect with this code.

```
            Intent ntent = new Intent();
            ntent.setClassName("com.project.test",
                    "com.project.test.MainActivity");
            ntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

            ntent.putExtras(bundle);

            int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
            ntent.setFlags(flags);

            //startActivity(ntent);
```